# Linkedin oauth2 PKCE Internal server error

Tags: linkedin-api

When i try to implement the 3 legged oauth flow as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow-native), i get a `Bummer, something went wrong.` error message without any indications beside this `Internal Server Error`.

I'm launching this call:

```
GET https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/native-pkce/authorization?
response_type=code
&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]
&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]
&state=[STATE]
&scope=r_liteprofile
&code_challenge=[CHALLENGE]
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

I assume it's related to the computation of the challenge parameters, but i've test on other oauth providers (like auth0) and it works properly. Has anyone ever encountered the same error?